# How can a mode be prevented from changing syntax coloring?

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting

The theme I'm using on emacs (zenburn) makes JDEE custom syntax coloring very hard to read. I'd like JDEE to obey the color theme I've already chosen.

Is there a simple way to prevent a mode from changing the syntax coloring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the theme itself make use of font-lock?

If not, then just turn off `font-lock-mode` in the mode (JDEE mode or whatever). `font-lock-mode` is buffer-local.